# Filter List of Tuples to Exclude from Another List of Tuples which Contains

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

(Using Python3)

I have a list of tuples, (of strings)

```
have = [
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'f'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'g'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e'),
 ('a', 'b', 'd', 'f'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'g'), ('a', 'b', 'e', 'f'), ('a', 'b', 'e', 'g'), ('a', 'b', 'f', 'g'),
 ('a', 'c', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'd', 'f'), ('a', 'c', 'd', 'g'), ('a', 'c', 'e', 'f'), ('a', 'c', 'e', 'g'),
 ('a', 'c', 'f', 'g'), ('a', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('a', 'd', 'e', 'g'), ('a', 'd', 'f', 'g'), ('a', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
 ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'd', 'f'), ('b', 'c', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'c', 'e', 'f'), ('b', 'c', 'e', 'g'),
 ('b', 'c', 'f', 'g'), ('b', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('b', 'd', 'e', 'g'), ('b', 'd', 'f', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
 ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('c', 'd', 'e', 'g'), ('c', 'd', 'f', 'g'), ('c', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')
 ]
```

I also have a list of tuples (also strings) which I want to "exclude"

```
 exclude = [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c')]
```

I'm trying to find an efficient way to remove any element in `have` that contains both the elements in each `exclude` tuple. Ordering does not matter.

My goal is to return something like this:

```
[
 ('a', 'b', 'e', 'f'), ('a', 'b', 'e', 'g'), ('a', 'b', 'f', 'g'), ('a', 'c', 'e', 'f'), ('a', 'c', 'e', 'g'),
 ('a', 'c', 'f', 'g'), ('a', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('b', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('b', 'd', 'e', 'g'), ('b', 'd', 'f', 'g'), 
 ('b', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('c', 'd', 'e', 'g'), ('c', 'd', 'f', 'g'), ('c', 'e', 'f', 'g'), 
 ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')
 ]
```

Comment: `[t for t in have if not any(set(x)&set(t)==set(x) for x in exclude)]`

Comment: Why don't you just produce the desired result directly, instead of producing too many and then filtering?

Comment: @superbrain because the two lists are created by a separate processes that do not have a connection to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the `exclude` tuples to `set`s and then check for each element of `have` is the excluded set isn't a subset of it:

```py
excludeSet = [set(e) for e in exclude]
filteredHave = [h for h in have if not any(e for e in excludeSet if e.issubset(h))]
```